# SQL Questions with data cleaning and frequency

Tags: sql, postgresql

i just encountered a SQL question , but i'm new to this , hope someone can give me some advises how to do it.

Assume Employees are voting for their favorite cafe. Each employee is allowed to vote as many
times as they want, but their vote gets split every time they vote and they cannot do duplicate
votes.

```
employees   cafe_name
A             Freddo
A             crumpets
A             Freddo
B
B             Bristo
C             nando
C             nando
```

a. Does the data require any cleaning or validation? How would you go about doing this?

b. Write a SQL statement to work out which cafe won

c. Suppose this vote is going to be performed again in the following year. What
improvements would you suggest to streamline the process?

d. Imagine this vote is then executed once every year and the data now has a field called
date . What interesting questions would you want to answer?

This is definitely not my homework, it's just an interview question that i'm not selected, but I want to know how to do it, hope someone can give me some answers

Answer (score 1):

Which Cafe won:

```
select  cafe_name, count(cafe_name) vote_count
from
(select distinct employee, cafe_name
from vote) v
group by cafe_name
order by vote_count desc
```

The subquery `select distinct employee, cafe_name from vote` eliminates the duplicate votes on a cafe by an employee.

Answer (score 0):

- Cafe Won:

This query will give the distinct employees vote count against the cafe name
the first cafe is the winner.

if every year the voting is going to happen , then may be we can show the history of cafename win by every year wise.

***Query :***
select cafe_name,count(distinct employees) as votes
from employee_votes
where (cafe_name is not null or cafe_name != '')
group by cafe_name order by votes desc